# How are the services exactly starting in (K)Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, startup, init, kubuntu, initrd

I have latest Kubuntu. I have installed mysql.
I was looking into the /etc/init.
I see the following:

```
In /etc/init/mysql.conf

description     "MySQL Server"                                                                                                                                                         [18/40]  
author          "Mario Limonciello <superm1@ubuntu.com>"  

start on runlevel [2345]  
stop on starting rc RUNLEVEL=[016]
```

If I understand this correctly mysql should start on level 2 and be up in all levels 2 up to 5.
Then I did the following:

```
Linux:/etc$ ls rc0.d/  
K10unattended-upgrades  K20kerneloops  README  S20sendsigs  S30urandom  S31umountnfs.sh  S40umountfs  S48cryptdisks  S59cryptdisks-early  S60umountroot  S90halt  
Linux:/etc$ ls rc1.d/  
K20kerneloops  K20saned  README  S30killprocs  S70dns-clean  S70pppd-dns  S90single  
Linux:/etc$ ls rc2.d/  
README  S20kerneloops  S50rsync  S50saned  S70dns-clean  S70pppd-dns  S75sudo  S99grub-common  S99ondemand  S99rc.local  
Linux:/etc$ ls rc3.d/  
README  S20kerneloops  S50rsync  S50saned  S70dns-clean  S70pppd-dns  S75sudo  S99grub-common  S99ondemand  S99rc.local  
Linux:/etc$ ls rc4.d/  
README  S20kerneloops  S50rsync  S50saned  S70dns-clean  S70pppd-dns  S75sudo  S99grub-common  S99ondemand  S99rc.local  
Linux:/etc$ ls rc5.d/    
README  S20kerneloops  S50rsync  S50saned  S70dns-clean  S70pppd-dns  S75sudo  S99grub-common  S99ondemand  S99rc.local
```

I was expecting that the mysqld would be listed in one of those directories.
I mean the services have the .conf files in the /etc/init and for each runtime level there is a link to the service executable to start/stop.
But why there is nothing for mysql?
Please note that mysql is up and running:

```
Linux:/etc$ ps -ef|grep mysql  
mysql      994     1  0 21:24 ?        00:00:08 /usr/sbin/mysqld  
jim      4396  4223  0 23:44 pts/8    00:00:00 grep --color=auto mysql
```

Comment: Ubuntu uses Upstart for its Init, which doesn't use /etc/rcX.d the way SysVInit does.  More information: http://upstart.ubuntu.com/

Comment: @samiam You should have answered the question with that.

Comment: Your right.  I don't use upstart (CentOS guy mainly), so couldn't give him an explicit "here's where to look for system startup scripts" answer. Since it hasn't been answered, I will do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu uses Upstart for its Init, which doesn't use /etc/rcX.d the way SysVInit does. More information: http://upstart.ubuntu.com/